# get number of gif frames without having to decode all data

Tags: c++, imagemagick

Is there a way I can get the number of image frames using ImageMagick without having to decode all the data to list< Image > like the way readImages does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Magick++ library has the `Magick::Image.ping` method to read the header info & not the image data.

As GeeMack pointed out, you need to only read the last frame (with `[-1]` suffix), and adjust.

```cpp
Magick::Image temp;
size_t total_frames = 0;

temp.ping("animation.gif[-1]");
total_frames = temp.scene() + 1;
```

Comment: do you know how to read the last frame using `ping ( const Blob &blob_ );`?

Comment: Can't think of a Magick++ way for working with blobs + protocols. But if you already have the file in memory, you can just scan the binary for all occurrence of `0x21` (followed by `0xF9` + `0x04`).

Comment: ok then. I have already thought of doing so. just wanted to find an easier way.

Answer (score 3):

Using ImageMagick version 6 from a command line you can do this...

```
convert input.gif[-1] -format %[scene] info:
```

That should read only the last frame and output its frame number, which is one less than the total number of frames.

You can get IM to add one to that number with a little trick setting and reading fake paging information like this...

```
convert input.gif[-1] -set page +%[scene] -format %[fx:page.x+1] info:
```

That should output the total number of frames in the GIF.

If using IM version 7 use "magick" instead of "convert".

Comment: Thanks, but I'm asking about the api. do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Another way in Imagemagick, at least on Unix systems, in command line, you can do the following piping from Imagemagick to wc (word count, which can count lines using wc -l):

## Create 3 frame gif

```
convert logo: logo: logo: logo.gif
```

## Get number of frames

```
convert logo.gif -format "%n\n" info: | wc -l 
       3
```

See string formats at https://imagemagick.org/script/escape.php

Comment: Thanks, but I'm asking about the api. do you have any ideas?